# Prove that $\phi= \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k \mathcal{X}_{(x_{k-1}, x_k)} $ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define a real-valued function $f$ which has a domain $D =[x, y] \subset \mathbb{R} $, and there is a partition $x = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = y$ of $[x, y] $ and $c_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\phi= \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k \mathcal{X}_{(x_{k-1}, x_k)} $$

Prove that $f$ is measurable if $\mathcal{X}$ is a characteristic function.

Attempt: The domain $D$ is measurable, so I just need to show that for every $\epsilon >0$, $\{f > \epsilon \} = \{x : f(x) > \epsilon \}$ is also measurable. But how can I do this?

Comment: $f$ or $\varphi?$

Comment: It is the union of the intervals $(x_{k-1},x_k)$ over all $k$ such that $c_k >\epsilon$.

Comment: What are you referring with "It..."?